# Running the contributed command: 'qiskit-vscode.runQiskitCode' failed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, qiskit

I am running VSCode on MacBook Air with Python and Qiskit extensions. I have installed python 3 via the macOS terminal. I am trying to run a test Qiskit code to draw a simple quantum circuit. When I run the code with "Run This Python" button, three windows pop up on the lower right corned, one of which says "Running" and the other two indicate errors (See screenshot). And nothing happens, no output in the terminal. However, python launcher flashes for a fraction of a second and disappears and nothing happens.

Any help on this issue will be really appreciated. Sorry if it's not much information (I am new to programming). If any further information is necessary to help me troubleshoot this issue, please let me know.[Screenshot: Running the contributed command: 'qiskit-vscode.runQiskitCode' failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1gg4.png)

Answer (score 0):

To show a matplotlib figure, you should add `plt.show()` at the end (if you use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`).  Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.draw('mpl')
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you can save the figure using `qc.draw('mpl', filename='my_circuit.png')`.